# Lxpanel crashes on vncserver startup

Tags: raspbian, vnc

So I've got some use out of tightVNC on other platforms (OS X) and I'm just getting my new RPi 2 B up and running. I'm using SSH to get to my RPi for now but I'd like to have a remote GUI and I assume vnc is the way to go. However lxpanel seems to crash every time I try to start up the server:

```
ben@raspberrypi:~ $ vncserver :0

New 'X' desktop is raspberrypi:0

Starting applications specified in /home/ben/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/ben/.vnc/raspberrypi:0.log

ben@raspberrypi:~ $ *** stack smashing detected ***: lxpanel terminated
```

Anyone have any pointers for how to troubleshoot this?

Other info:
processor: ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
os: raspbian

**EDIT 1: From /home/ben/.vnc/raspberrypi:0.log:**

```
27/01/16 13:03:17 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
27/01/16 13:03:17 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
27/01/16 13:03:17 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
27/01/16 13:03:17 All Rights Reserved.
27/01/16 13:03:17 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
27/01/16 13:03:17 Desktop name 'X' (raspberrypi:0)
27/01/16 13:03:17 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
27/01/16 13:03:17 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5900
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
xrdb: No such file or directory
xrdb: can't open file '/home/ben/.Xresources'
```

Comment: what does the log file say: /home/ben/.vnc/raspberrypi:0.log?

Comment: Are you trying to start tightvncserver from inside the GUI? How are you trying to start tightvncserver? From the log this seems to be using desktop :0, but the rest of the log looks OK. What are you doing on the other end?

Comment: I was thinking along those lines too, but on my system vncserver says :0 is already taken. It seems the problem is not vncserver, but rather lxpanel. Is  it possible to startx with a monitor on the hdmi port?

Comment: I am starting it from the cli over ssh using the command I posted originally.

Answer (score 0):

You must create and empty file in the home's folder. I mean the home folder for the user who is launching the vncserver. It seems in your case should be `/home/ben`, so you can do it using for example the cmd: `touch /home/ben/.Xresources` but after this the success is not warranted. Maybe after this you can get another error. Will see. Good luck!